# Pivot table with join other table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pivot-table

I wanna ask about pivot table with join other table. Its look like this below:

**Result**

```
|   DATE    | A | B  | C  | D  |
|-----------|---|----|----|----|
|2015-06-01 |10 | 20 | 30 | 20 |
|2015-06-02 |20 | 30 | 40 | 20 |
|2015-06-03 |40 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
```

That table came from this two table below:

**Table Master**

```
|ID|Type|
|--|----|
|1 |A   |
|2 |B   |
|3 |C   |
```

**Table Type**

```
|ID|Date      | idType |value|
|--|----------|--------|-----|
|1 |2015-06-01| 1      | 10  |
|2 |2015-06-01| 2      | 20  |
|3 |2015-06-01| 3      | 30  |
|4 |2015-06-01| 4      | 20  |
|5 |2015-06-02| 1      | 20  |
|6 |2015-06-02| 2      | 30  |
|7 |2015-06-02| 3      | 40  |
|8 |2015-06-02| 4      | 20  |
|9 |2015-06-03| 1      | 40  |
|10|2015-06-03| 2      | 10  |
|11|2015-06-03| 3      | 10  |
|12|2015-06-03| 4      | 20  |
```

I tried this code below, but its not succsess.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT tgl_nab, idtype, nilai FROM jts_test ) src pivot (sum(nilai) for idtype in ([1], [2], [3],[4]) ) piv;
```

The error show like this below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'pivot (sum(nilai) for idtype in ([1], [2], [3],[4]) ) piv LIMIT
>   0, 25' at line 1

And i have other related question too. How do show the result table in view codeigniter. Let say i have a controller to select all data, like this code below:

```
public function test()
{
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$data['test'] = $this->report_m->get_allcontentest();
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('report/test_list_view',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');
} else {
    redirect('login');
}
}
```

and i dont how the model work, is it write the same query as when i get the result. or maybe there is other way.
also in the view its complicated i guess. here's the view i made.

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
          <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th><?php echo $baris->type; ?></th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Menu</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                foreach($report as $baris){
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $baris->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $baris->nilai; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $baris->create; ?></td>
                <td>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-eye"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

really appriciete your help.

Comment: Syntax suggests mysql,removed the sql server tag

Comment: replace with what? @Mihai

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: Acctually i wanna get the result like table result above @Mihai

Comment: Can you provide a  SQL fiddle

Comment: i have tried like this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15b9d/5) but it not join. field type i write by myself @Uchiha

Comment: why i made master table because, in the future field type will be add new value. example, there is will be type E,F,or G @Uchiha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36838/13/3)

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN m.idType = ',
      Id,
      ' THEN value END) AS ',
      Type
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tblType;

SET @sql =
  CONCAT('SELECT m.Date, ', @sql, ' FROM tblMaster m INNER JOIN tblType t ON t.Id = m.idType GROUP BY m.Date ORDER BY m.Date');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Read this [**article**](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) for more information on dynamic pivots.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!